# Could you please explain the following code?

Tags: node.js

Here what exactly the ***var app = express();*** means?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.send('Hello World');
})
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
var host = server.address().address
var port = server.address().port
console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

Comment: its an express server, have a look at their docs https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Comment: The Statement  `var app = express();`  calls a function from express module which creates server application object and returns it which you can access via `app` variable.                                                                                           
if You are interested to explore the code see the [express.js](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js)

Answer (score 1):

When the following statement is run,

```
var express = require('express');
```

the variable express gets assigned to the export value of the module `express`. In this case, the module exports a function, which returns some object.

So when the following statement runs,

```
var app = express();
```

the variable `app` gets assigned the object returned by the function.

Answer (score 0):

express()-Creates an Express application. The express() function is a top-level 
function exported by the express module.

Link to API doc for express:
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Do have look into API documents before posting questions,it might help you to understand basics.